# Clearing sector zero of a removable media device

Tags: wpf, usb-drive

I need to clear sector 0 for removable media devices (custom USB memory devices) which I have been trying to clear within a WPF/C# application.  My first attempt was to use [DD](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd), but I ran into problems.  During the manufacturing of the devices a MBR is created at sector 0 and the volume (logical?) starts at sector 40.  When I issue the following command it clears sector 40 and not sector 0:

`dd bs=512 count=1 if=/dev/zero of=\.\E:`

I found another version of DD [here](http://gmgsystemsinc.com/fau/) which includes a wipe utility.  I tried this version and I am seeing the same behavior.  I am using both HxD and Runtime's DiskExplorer that sector 40 is being cleared and not sector 0.  I could use HxD or Runtime's DiskExplorer, but this needs to be scriptable.

Does anyone know of any other methods of clearing (filling) sector 0 within Windows XP SP2??  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Mark

Solution: My solution used WMI to find the physical drive based upon the logical drive letter.  First, query the Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition class to find the logical drive I am looking for. This provides the Antecedent field which constains something like '...DeviceID="Disk #X, Partition #Y"'.  Next, I query Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition class while searching against the Dependent field to find the match for the Antecedent field within the Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition class.  Once found, the Antecedent field from Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition will yield the physical drive. I selected atzz since it is the closes to my solution.  I wanted to use Eugene's suggestion, but I only had a few hours to implement this so I selected the easier of the two.  I will need to revisit this at a later time though.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the mention of DD. I didn't know a Windows port existed. It's rarely needed, but very useful sometimes. Now I won't have to boot linux just for dd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to format a USB drive, from Windows standpoint:

- As a floppy disk. In this case entire USB drive contains a single file system, and its boot record is located in sector 0.
- As a hard drive. In this case, sector 0 contains [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) with partition table. Actual file system(s) with their individual boot records are located further on the drive.

I think you are observing the second case. Using \.\E: to identify the device, you end up accessing file system's boot record instead of MBR.

Here is how you can access sector 0 of the USB drive.

1. Load WinObj from [here](http://live.sysinternals.com/Winobj.exe).
2. In WinObj, under `GLOBAL??`, find E:. It will be a SymbolicLink pointing to something like `\Device\Harddisk2\DP(1)0-0+30`.
3. Under `GLOBAL??`, find a PhysicalDrive# symlink referring to the same Harddisk# that you found on step 2. Most probably it will have the same numeric suffix as Harddisk#. E.g.: SymbolicLink `PhysicalDrive2` refers to `\Device\Harddisk2\DR47`.
4. Use the PhysicalDrive# you've found in DD command:

   `dd bs=512 count=1 if=\\.\PhysicalDrive2 of=mbr.dat`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to clear logical device E: and not physical device. Try doing the following:

call [CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) WinAPI function to open "\\.\PhysicalDriveX" where X is the number of the device (see Remarks in description of CreateFile function for information about how to open the physical device properly). Then use WriteFile API function to write 512 bytes at offset 0 of the opened device.

If you get permission denied error when opening the device for writing, you can take our [RawDisk](http://www.eldos.com/rawdisk/) product (trial version will work fine for you) which lets one bypass this security measure of Windows.

upd: As for calling CreateFile from C#, see [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CreateFile).